# How to gotTo specific page using ngx-bootstrap pagination

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, react-native

I have a query where I need to implement: How to gotTo a specific page using
ngx- bootstrap pagination by entering the page number to some input field.

Here is the following code snippet :

```
***Template:***


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-item" *ngFor="let content of returnedArray">{{content}}</p>
    </div>
    <pagination [totalItems]="contentArray.length" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"></pagination>
  </div>
</div>



**.ts file**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageChangedEvent } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';

@Component({
    // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/component-selector
    selector: 'demo-pagination-content-switching',
    templateUrl: './content-switching.html',
    styles: [`
.content-wrapper {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 4px;
padding-left: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
`]
})
export class DemoPaginationContentSwitchingComponent implements OnInit {
    contentArray = new Array(90).fill('');
    returnedArray?: string[];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.contentArray = this.contentArray.map((v: string, i: number) => `Content line ${i + 1}`);
        this.returnedArray = this.contentArray.slice(0, 10);
    }

    pageChanged(event: PageChangedEvent): void {
        const startItem = (event.page - 1) * event.itemsPerPage;
        const endItem = event.page * event.itemsPerPage;
        this.returnedArray = this.contentArray.slice(startItem, endItem);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/pagination?tab=overview); you can bind `pagination` with `[(ngModel)]` to keep it synced with a particular instance member.

In your `DemoPaginationContentSwitchingComponent` declare a variable `currentPage` and bind it with Angular Bootstraps's `pagination` component like this

```
<pagination [totalItems]="contentArray.length (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentPage"></pagination>
```

Now add the `input` you want to control the `pagination` with, you can either listen to `(changed)` event of this `input` and set the `currentPage` value accordingly, or simply add a `button` to do that.

Either way, you need to validate this input in order to avoid errors coming from the `pagination` component.